# Is Kubuntu Debian-based? and installing alongside Windows 8

Tags: debian, system-installation, windows, kubuntu

Kubuntu is part of the Ubuntu project. Is it also compatible with all debian software, isn't it? So are all softwares made (or certainly-compatible) for Ubuntu (i.e. Software Center, Steam, Blender, Eclipse, etc...)

I'm asking because I'd like to install it alongside my windows 8 (not 8.1) partition, do you have any special recommendations for this? Should I upgrade to 8.1 before?

Comment: Ubuntu is a derivative distribution of Debian, and Kubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu. Therefore, Kubuntu is a derivative of Debian. As for "compatible with all debian software,", it depends what you mean by "compatible". In general you cannot assume that derivative distributions have binary level compatibility with each other, or with their parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubuntu work fine alongside Windows 8.

You can follow this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. Even if it's mean for Ubuntu vanilla, the Kubuntu use the same installer (Ubiquity).

Comment: I won't loose the windows 8 OEM key on the motherboard, will I? Just in case of disaster, I'd like the possibility of recovering through Win8 rescue CD

Comment: you won't loose it, but remember to use the same install disk than the first time you installed Windows (or the associated rescue disk). Because Windows use the CD identifier and the CD key to activate Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run the "standard" Ubuntu packages on Kubuntu (and the other way around). The underlying X server handles either KDE or Gnome based graphical applications.

The only thing you have to reckon with, is that on the first install of such a package a bunch of gnome related packages will be installed. But once they are there, other packages will install faster.